# How to render text inside jsx "tag" like a normal HTML?

Tags: reactjs

Just to get you into the context, I am using React SSR and I get the following error:

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Vehicles Array (114)" Client: "Vehicles Array ("
```

When I looked into it, this part of the DOM looks like following:

```
"Vehicles Array ("
"114"
")"
```

My React code looks like the following:

```
<p>Vehicles Array ({vehicles.length})</p>
```

How do I get rid of this error? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I want it to look like "Vehicles Array (114)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you want?

```
<p>{'Vehicles Array (' + vehicles.length + ')'}</p>
```

or with template literals:

```
<p>{`Vehicles Array (${vehicles.length})`}</p>
```

Comment: Yes, but since I am doing this so many times, isn't there a better way of doing it? Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @PhilipFabianek Yes, write a new component or a small function.